# Validar quantidade minima de caracteres em textarea?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Bom pessoal, estou precisando validar um campo textarea numa aplicação usando thymeleaf, para limitar a quantidade máxima já consegui, mas não sei como validar a quantidade minima.

Comment: Como que está seu código?

Comment: Consegui, achei que somente adicionar minlength="qtd" não funcionária diretamente no HTML, mas deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui, bastou adicionar minlength=" " com a quantidade que necessitava que deu certo.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="inputAnswer" placeholder="Enter Question" th:field="*{answer}" minlength="50" maxlength="255">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('answer')}" th:errors="*{answer}" th:class="help-block" />
</textarea>
```